# What is an idiomatic way to measure time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3

This is pretty ugly:

```
t = Time.now
result = do_something
elapsed = Time.now - t
```

I tried this:

```
elapsed = time do
  result = do_something
end

def time
  t = Time.now
  yield
  Time.now - t
end
```

This is better. But the problem is that `result` falls out of scope after the block ends.

So, is there a better way of doing timing? Or a good way to use the `result`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really idiomatic way would be to use the standard library. :)

```
require 'benchmark'

result = nil
elapsed = Benchmark.realtime do 
  result = do_something
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea here, but to avoid the scope problem do this:

```
result = nil
elapsed = time do
  result = do_something
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the way you've constructed your `time` method. I have no suggestions for improvement, but I will say a few words about a related problem. Suppose you wished to measure the amount of time spent executing methods. Sometimes you might be able to write something simple such as:

```
require 'time'

t = Time.now
rv = my_method(*args)
et = t.Time.now - t
```

Other times that's not convenient. Suppose, for example, you were constructing an array whose elements were the return values of `my_method` or `my_method` returned an enumerator so that it could be chained to other methods.

As an example, let's suppose you wanted to sum the values of an array until a zero is encountered. One way to do that is to construct an enumerator `stop_at_zero` that generates values from its receiver until it encounters a zero, then stops (i.e., raises a `StopIteration` exception). We could then write:

```
arr.stop_at_zero.reduce(:+)
```

If we want to know how much time is spent executing `stop_at_zero` we could construct it as follows.

```
class Array
  def stop_at_zero
    extime = Time.now
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      begin
        each do |n|
          sleep(0.5)
          return y if n.zero?
          y << n
        end
      ensure
        $timings << [__method__, Time.now - extime]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I used a `begin`, `ensure`, `end` block to make sure `$timings << [__method__, Time.now - extime]` is executed when the method returns prematurely. `sleep(0.5)` is of course just for illustrative purposes.

Let's try it.

```
$timings = []
arr = [1,7,0,3,4]
arr.stop_at_zero.reduce(:+)
  #=> 8 
$timings
  #=> [[:stop_at_zero, 1.505672]]
```

`$timings` will contain a history of execution times of all methods that contain the timing code.